# R: adding two regression line with same data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am plotting regression line for my data. Here is the data i have

```
library(car)
data(Sahlins)
m1<- lm(acres~consumers,data=Sahlins)
```

then i delete row 4, get a new data set as below.

```
Sahlins[-c( 4), ]
a<- Sahlins[-c( 4), ]
m2 <- lm(acres~consumers,data=a)
```

I try to adding two regression line (m1, and m2) for original data set Sahlins. but it just not work. Only work with   two separate plot . here is the r code i have.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Sahlins,aes(consumers,acres))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F) 
ggplot(a,aes(consumers,acres))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F)
```

how can i  get two regression line in one plot ? this is the plot i want. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CJol.png)
Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(car)
data(Sahlins)

ggplot(Sahlins, aes(consumers, acres)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F) +
  geom_smooth(data = Sahlins[-4, ], method="lm", se=F)
```

[image]

Comment: @Yansisi If this solution works, please accept this as the answer.