# Ggplot: 1 Regression line with constant and 1 without

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a university exercise, I would like to plot two regression lines in the same graph: one regression includes a constant, the other one doesn't. It should illustrate how removing the constant changes the regression line.

However, when I use the following ggplot-command, I only get one regression line. Does anybody know the reason for this and how to fix it?

```
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +    # Scatters
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, aes(color='red'),
              formula = y ~ x -0, #remove constant
              se=FALSE)
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611106/r-adding-two-regression-line-with-same-data), but it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: You've already gotten the answer below, but as a side note: `color = 'red'` does not need to be within `aes()` for your second `geom_smooth` layer.

Comment: ah perfect, this was really annoying me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it; to remove the intercept, you need `+ 0` or `- 1`, but not `- 0`; from `help("lm")`:

> A formula has an implied intercept term. To remove this use either y ~
>   x - 1 or y ~ 0 + x. See formula for more details of allowed formulae.

So, we can do this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg)) +
    geom_point() +    # Scatters
    geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)+
    geom_smooth(method=lm, aes(color='red'),
                formula = y ~ x - 1, #remove constant
                se=FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick! Thanks a lot and also for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

good day,

the good book said to do it like this: 
http://bighow.org/questions/18280770/formatting-regression-line-equation-using-ggplot2-in-r
I cant take credit for the code writing but the research ...

Have a great day...
captbullett